# GroupBy but still keep all rows

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, group-by

I have this DataFrame

```
data = [[1,'A','a'],
        [1,'A','b'],
        [1,'B','a'],
        [2,'A','a'],
        [2,'A','b'],
        [2,'A','c']]

df_1 = pd.DataFrame(data = data,columns = ['id','Main','sub_steps'])
```

output

```
   id Main Sub_steps
0   1    A         a
1   1    A         b
2   1    B         a
3   2    A         a
4   2    A         b
5   2    A         c
```

I want to groupby (id, Main) and still keep all rows

Desired Output

```
   id Main Sub_steps      lst
0   1    A         a    [a,b]
1   1    A         b    [a,b]
2   1    B         a      [a]
3   2    A         a  [a,b,c]
4   2    A         b  [a,b,c]
5   2    A         c  [a,b,c]
```

If I just do a group by with id and main and flatten the other row

```
df_1.groupby(['id','Main']).agg({'Sub_steps':list})
```

I will get this

```
         Sub_steps
id Main           
1  A        [a, b]
   B           [a]
2  A     [a, b, c]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `merge` on column names with a renaming the pd.Series returned by `groupby` with `agg`:

```
df_1.merge(df_1.groupby(['id','Main'])['sub_steps'].agg(list).rename('lst'),
           on=['id', 'Main']))
```

Output:

```
   id Main sub_steps        lst
0   1    A         a     [a, b]
1   1    A         b     [a, b]
2   1    B         a        [a]
3   2    A         a  [a, b, c]
4   2    A         b  [a, b, c]
5   2    A         c  [a, b, c]
```

You can merge the output of your aggregation back to your original dataframe.

Answer (score 4):

Another approach, with `.transform()`:

```
df_1['lst'] = df_1.groupby(['id','Main'])['sub_steps'].transform(lambda x: [list(x) for v in x])
print(df_1)
```

Prints:

```
   id Main sub_steps        lst
0   1    A         a     [a, b]
1   1    A         b     [a, b]
2   1    B         a        [a]
3   2    A         a  [a, b, c]
4   2    A         b  [a, b, c]
5   2    A         c  [a, b, c]
```