# Replace column values with smallest value in group

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, fill

I have a dataframe which looks similar to this:

```
Group    |     Value
-----------------------
 A       |      1
 A       |      4     
 A       |      5
 B       |      10      
 B       |      7
 B       |      15
```

Basically, what I want to do is fill in the `Value` column with the smallest value based on the unique value given in the `Group` column, such that I get a dataframe like this:

```
Group    |     Value
-----------------------
 A       |      1
 A       |      1      
 A       |      1
 B       |      7      
 B       |      7
 B       |      7
```

i.e. since `1` is the smallest value for `Group A`, change everything to `1` and since `7` is the smallest value for `Group B`, change everything in `Group B` to `7`

I'm not sure what to do for this, so any help would be appreciated!

Comment: `df.groupby('Group')['Value'].transform('min')`

Comment: duplicates https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62761820/groupby-but-still-keep-all-rows

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as follows:

```
  import pandas as pd
    
    # Create the example dataframe
    df = pd.DataFrame({'Group': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B'], 'Value': [1, 4, 5, 10, 7, 15]})
    
    # Group the dataframe by 'Group' and find the minimum value in each group
    min_values = df.groupby('Group')['Value'].transform('min')
    
    # Assign the minimum values to the 'Value' column
    df['Value'] = min_values
    
    # Print the resulting dataframe
    print(df)
```